# Strange error while doing a multiplication in java?

Tags: java, android

```
public static int NUM_FRAMES = 8;
public static int FRAME_REPEAT_NO = 2;
int height = 24;
//bitmap.getWidth() is 168 and bitmap.getHeight() is 91

double w = bitmap.getWidth();
w = w/NUM_FRAMES;
w = w*FRAME_REPEAT_NO;
w = w*height;
w = w/bitmap.getHeight();
```

I do this and i get the value of `w` as 11.07 which is correct.

But when i do this:

```
double w  = FRAME_REPEAT_NO*(bitmap.getWidth()/NUM_FRAMES)*(height/bitmap.getHeight());
```

value of `w` is always 0;

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

P.S. I'm doing it in an android app...

Comment: Please post the errorlog...!!

Comment: @BBExpert There is no error log; the results were just different than udiboy was expecting.

Comment: In your question you wrote "Strange error while doing a multiplication". thats why i ask for the error log. Ok nop your problem will solved by JigarJosi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have already addressed your question, so I won't repeat their answers, but one suggestion I'll make. Consider computing your result using

`w = (double)(FRAME_REPEAT_NO * bitmap.getWidth() * height) / (double)(NUM_FRAMES * bitmap.getHeight())`

This allows you to live in the predictable land of integers until the very end where you do the division. So any error in the result comes from a single operation instead of aggregating multiple errors. And if for whatever reason you decided you wanted to get an integer result, you can drop the doubles and still get 11 as the answer.

Not a big deal but just thought I'd put it out there.

**EDIT:** I saw from your comment on another post that you actually want the 11. Good. So just drop the doubles altogether:

`w = (FRAME_REPEAT_NO * bitmap.getWidth() * height) / (NUM_FRAMES * bitmap.getHeight())`

Answer is exactly 11 (integer), which is different by the way than the floating point approximation of 11.0.

Comment: Thanks @WillieWheeler. exactly what i wanted!

Comment: My pleasure. Just keep in mind that floating point numbers are inherently approximations. You should not use them for situations that require exact quantities, like currency calculations. It's tricky because currency involves decimals so it looks like you should use floats. Nope.

Answer (score 1):

Cast `int` to `double`

```
double w  = FRAME_REPEAT_NO*(bitmap.getWidth()/((double)NUM_FRAMES))*(height/((double)bitmap.getHeight()));
```

Comment: OK! @JigarJoshi that worked. But why wasn't it happening with ints?

Comment: `height/bitmap.getHeight()` (24/91), according to integer division, is 0.

Comment: If you divide int/int, the result will also be int, and you loose the fractional part.

Comment: so (FRAME_REPEAT_NO*bitmap.getWidth()*height)/(NUM_FRAMES*bitmap.getHeight()) should work the same way right?

Comment: @udiboy: You will get integer division again, since both operands are integer.

Comment: Check the answer and see `(double)` casting

Comment: Actually the w is a width parameter for a bitmap so i wanted an int. And i checked it. It gives me 11.0 which is exactly what i want! And i avoid the double casting too!

Answer (score 1):

You're using integer arithmetic in a situation that requires floating point arithmetic:

```
double w = FRAME_REPEAT_NO*(bitmap.getWidth()/NUM_FRAMES)*(height/bitmap.getHeight());
//     w =              2 * (168             / 8       ) * (  24 / 91);
//     w =              2 * (21                        ) * ( 0 );
//     w = 0;
```

As @JigarJoshi pointed out, the solution is to make sure you use floating point arithmetic. You can cast as per his suggestion, or you can do something like this:

```
public static float NUM_FRAMES = 8.0f;
public static float FRAME_REPEAT_NO = 2.0f;
float height = 24.0f;

float w  = FRAME_REPEAT_NO * (bitmap.getWidth() / NUM_FRAMES) *
                             (height / bitmap.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the **BODMAS** RULE... I got the desired output using this rule...

Highest to Lowest priority..

**B - Brackets**

**O - Power**

**DM - Divison and Multiplication**

**AS - Addition and Substraction**

```
 w =  ((w/NUM_FRAMES)*(FRAME_REPEAT_NO)*(height))/bitmap.getHeight();
```

**Output:**

```
    11.076923076923077
```